# How to provide field type in XML datasource of ireport designer?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am newbie to the ireport designer.This question may simple for you.I have tried to XML file as data source and it worked.The problem is All the fields are coming as java.lang.string. How to provide the field type in XML datasource.Is it possible to provide field type in XML file itself. Consider

```
<customer>
  <name>obuli</name>
  <age><22></age>
  <subscriber>
    <name>sundar</name>
    <no_of_transactions>100</no_of_transactions>
  </subscriber>
</customer>
```

Here the customer and subscriber are classes so i need to provide filed type com.test.Customer,com.test.Subscriber. I can achieve this by java bean datasource. But still i need the XML datasource way.

Is it possible to set the field type in XML datasource way ?

Comment: Use should set the filed's type in report's template (*jrxml* file), for example with help of *iReport*

Answer (score 0):

I do not think so. I also do not think you need that feature as reports only require scalar values. So just map the scalar values in your datasource to your scalar valued report fields.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go on the XML code of your document and then search your field tag name, for example:

```
<field name="xxxx" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

change to Date type:

```
<field name="xxxx" class="java.util.Date"/>
```